# Unable to run any commands on gitbash: Not a Valid Identifier

Tags: git, git-bash

Every time I open Git Bash, I get the following message "not a valid identifier", and I cant run any commands. cd works, but ls, "pwd", mkdir, gives me the error "no such file or directory". I think it has to do with my bashrc files, but I cant figure it out.
[This is the commands I put in, and what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGsEl.jpg)

Comment: `cat .profile .bash_profile .bashrc` ?

Comment: You've almost certainly messed up your `PATH` setting. Somewhere outside of bash, run your editor on your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file, whichever one you used to create an `export PATH=` setting, and fix that. This has nothing to do with Git, it's purely a bash issue. Git-bash is just a port of bash to Windows, so that people with terrible development environments can get some decent tools. It's less needed now that Windows comes with better tooling (but it's still needed).